# How to deobfuscated javascript?

Tags: obfuscation, javascript

How to deobfuscate javascript file, i have a javascript code are deobfuscate .

---

Code: http://pastebin.com/zFH2GidN
Help me and thanks you.

Comment: I want decode not encode.

Comment: Did you try this http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28714/convert-jsfuck-to-normal-js

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Based on @ws's comment and @nderscore's code, use [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AcidShout/0fjcsw00/) to decode the thing.

---

To find the password that this script asks for, you can use a simple debugging trick.

- Go to [JSFuck](http://www.jsfuck.com/) and uncheck the `Eval Source` option.
- Paste the obfuscated JavaScript
- Run

You'll see:

[image]

It seems to be calling [`prompt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt), so put a breakpoint on it, like this:

*(I'll be using Chrome for this)*

- Open console (<kbd>F12</kbd>)
- Backup the original `prompt` like this: `window.prompt_ = window.prompt`
- Override the call to prompt with a breakpoint: `window.prompt = function(a, b){ debugger; return window.prompt_(a, b); }`
- Click `Run This`
- You'll break here:

[image]

- Check the callstack at the right bottom.
- Go back one function, and you'll see:

[image]

## Bingo!

Password is `forevermore`:

[image]
[image]